# I can't get the view ID/name in hook_preprocess_views_view_unformatted()

Tags: 8, views

In this function I can't get view ID/name.

```php
function THEMENAME_preprocess_views_view_unformatted($vars) {
  $view = $vars["view"];
  $id = $view->storage->id();  
  $name = $view->name;
}
```

In `hook_preprocess_views_view_fields()`, it works properly.  Why doesn't it work in `preprocess_views_view_unformatted()`?

Comment: I think your function's signature is wrong. Try [this](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view_unformatted/8.2.x) instead. Moreover, hooks step in at a different level rather than template functions.

Comment: it is correct its the same as the link ... i see it executing with the debugger

Comment: This is for Drupal 7 or Drupal 8?

Comment: its for Drupal 8

Comment: Did you check the theme preprocess is firing? try putting something like `kint('testing');` or `drupal_set_message('testing');` and see if it shows up.

Comment: @NoSssweat revised my question, yes it does

Comment: @GiorgosK [works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hS7HP.png) for me

Comment: @NoSssweat thanks for looking into this ... I can get it in other preprocess but on in `hook_preprocess_views_view_unformatted` !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the only way I could get view id (not sure why)

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_views_view_unformatted($vars){
  $view = $vars["view"];
  //works
  $id = $view->id();
}
```